# How to check for empty float values in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

My program has an entry widgets called pizza and sandwich. If the user begins typing in the pizza box the sandwich box should be disabled. If the user begins typing in the sandwich box then the pizza box should be disabled. Box entry boxes should take a float value. The user can pick either box to type the price when they finish typing they should click the submit button and the price should print out. I am trying to figure out how to check for empty floats so the if else statement can change state.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")


pizza = tk.DoubleVar()
sandwich = tk.DoubleVar()

def click(event):
    if pizza.get() != '':
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    if sandwich.get() != '':
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    if pizza.get() == '' and sandwich.get() == "":
        sandwich_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        pizza_entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    print("price: " + str(pizza))
    print("price: " + str(sandwich))

pizza_label = tk.Label(root, text='pizza')
pizza_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=pizza)
pizza_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', click)
sandwich_label = tk.Label(root, text='sandwich')
sandwich_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sandwich)
sandwich_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', click)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Submit',)


pizza_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
pizza_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
sandwich_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
sandwich_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Calling `.get()` on a `DoubleVar` cannot possibly return an empty string; it either returns a float, or it throws an error.  Doing the `.get()` inside a `try`-`except:` would be one solution.  Using a `StringVar` instead, and doing the conversion to float yourself after verify that the string isn't empty, would be another.

Comment: I suggest using `StringVar`s and doing the conversion to `float` manually inside a `try`/`except ValueError` which will handle otherwise malformed values in addition to empty strings. Also note that binding to `'<KeyRelease>'` means the event handler function will be called on every keystroke which is likely not desirable. It's possible to validate the contents of `Entry` widgets in more sophisticated ways than via simple key-press event handlers. See [Adding validation to an Entry widget](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/entry-validation.html).

Comment: P.S. Yet another alternative would be to **trace** changes to the tkinter Variables. See [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). Note that the `trace()` method was renamed `trace_add()` since very old linked documentation was written plus there are other related methods not mentioned in it like `trace_remove()` — so you should try to locate some more up-to-date information if you're interested.